# Why is [gatsby-plugin-image] missing image prop for JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, gatsby, gatsby-image

**Objective:** Read JSON data that has path of images, associated title, description and alt. The graphql will query the JSON data and display it in four cards. Title, description and alt works but the image does not work. Console.log displays: "[gatsby-plugin-image] Missing image prop"

```
const Expertise = () => {
    // query data
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query ExpertiseQuery {
            allExpertiseJson {
                edges {
                    node {
                        alt
                        description
                        title
                        img {
                            childImageSharp {
                                gatsbyImageData
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `)

    // iterate over JSON data
    function getExpertise(data) {
        const expertiseArray = []
        data.allExpertiseJson.edges.forEach((item, index) => {
            const image=getImage(item.node.img)
            expertiseArray.push(
                <ExpertiseCard key={index}>
                    <h3>{item.node.title}</h3>
                    <p>{item.node.description}</p>
                    <GatsbyImage>
                        image={image}
                        alt={item.node.alt}
                    </GatsbyImage>
                </ExpertiseCard>
            )
        })
        return expertiseArray
    }
    return (
        <ExpertiseContainer>
            <ExpertiseH1><span>|</span>Expertise</ExpertiseH1>
            <ExpertiseH2>Solution architect from lean design to agile development</ExpertiseH2>
            <CardContainer>
                {getExpertise(data)}
            </CardContainer>
        </ExpertiseContainer>
    )
}
```

JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Design Thinking",
        "description": "An ardent supporter of design thinking and emphathizing users to understand the entire spectrum of the problem space.",
        "img": "../images/design_thinking.jpg",
        "alt": "Design Thinking"
    },
    {
        "title": "Lean Startup",
        "description": "A practitioner of the Lean Startup principles for delivering business value and reduce product development cycle by designing MVP.",
        "img": "../images/design_thinking.jpg",
        "alt": "Design Thinking"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax issue at:

```
<GatsbyImage>
    image={image}
    alt={item.node.alt}
</GatsbyImage>
```

Here, you are wrapping the image within the `GatsbyImage` component while you need to pass the `image` prop to like:

```
<GatsbyImage
    image={image}
    alt={item.node.alt}
/>
```